# Can we remove or hide the Volunteer subclass in CiviVolunteer?

Tags: civivolunteer

We have implemented CiviVolunteer to manage our 30 projects across 118 volunteers.

The positives:

Projects are linked via Activities in sympathy with the overall CiviCRM design philosophy.

Once two bug fixes were applied, it now works as specified - all good.

The negatives:

The Volunteer subclass of Individual has popped up but is not used by CiviVolunteer for the actual volunteers. This is a bit confusing and instructions in our User Guide (thank you Echo Plugins for Knowledge Base for Documents and FAQs) are the way that we have dealt with this.

The Volunteer reports don't expose the two relationships (Owner or Manager).

The overall reporting system of CiviCRM doesn't appear to support (out of the box) summarisation of rows (e.g. a count of rows, a sum of values from a row, etc.).

Sounds like a lot of negatives, but we are using CiviVolunteer and are achieving a deal of acceptance from our users.

As requested in the guidelines, that's our story.

Now the questions is, can the Volunteer subclass be removed safely or safely hidden?

Regards,

Rob.

CiviCRM 5.4.1 PHP 7.1.24 CiviVolunteer 4.7.31-2.3.1 WordPress 4.9.8